# Best way to split a large JSON response into multiple objects and push them to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a large JSON response that I get back after an HTTP call that looks like this:

```
0: { index: 0, name: "bob", age: 12, location: "adelaide" ... }
1: { index: 0, name: "jeff", age: 23 ... }
2: { index: 1, name: "sam", age: 25 ... }
...
```

From this, I want to create an array of objects, with one object for each value of *index* and its corresponding entries, where I can choose what data goes into those entries. Something like this:

```
[
    { name: "index_0", index: 0, data: [{ name: "bob", age: 12  }, { name: "jeff", age: 23 }] },
    { name: "index_1", index: 1, data: [{ name: "sam", age: 25 }] },
    ...
]
```

I know I need to create objects dynamically here based on the index count, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const newdata = [];
origdata.forEach(function(item){
    if(!newdata[item.index])
        newdata[item.index] = {name:'index_'+item.index,index:item.index,data:[]};
    newdata[item.index].data.push(item);
    delete item.index;
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. One issue I'm experiencing is that when I run the forEach function on the original data, item is the entire array instead of each individual item in it. When I print it it looks like this: test : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]..... Should I start by converting this response before running the forEach?